# Categorizing a sub-expression within an expression

Tags: sql, subquery, formal-languages, operands

Let's say I have the following `select_expr`:

```
SELECT
    name,
    4 + (
       (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM tbl WHERE name=tbl.name)
       / (SELECT COUNT(revenue) FROM tbl WHERE name=tbl.name)
    )
FROM tbl
```

Ignoring the fact that this query doesn't make sense, I'm curious how the second `select_expr` would be categorized:

```
4  + (SELECT ...) / (SELECT ...)
```

I suppose all three items can be called 'operands' and the second two can be called 'sub-selects', but is there a better way to categorize that the "subselect" is only a component of the final select expression? Sorry if this is pedantic, but I'm looking for a clear way to categorize 'terms' within a complex expression.

Comment: (Ignoring the table alias confusion) You have two correlated (you’re filtering inside the subquery based on outside of it) scalar (returns one row with one column) subquery. You are treating these scalar subqueries like any other expression.

Comment: @AndrewSayer sure, but is there anyways to differentiate a terminal subquery and one that is part of a larger expression? Maybe this is just a general programming term and not a sql term.

Comment: You mean as part of the `select` clause rather than the `from` clause as a row source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> 4  + (SELECT ...) / (SELECT ...)
> ```

You have an arithmetic operation that involves three operands. The first operand is a constant, and the two other are *scalar subqueries*.

The term *subquery* indicates that this is an intermediate result in the whole query. *scalar* means that the subquery returns just one row, with one column (or, possibly, no row at all - but that's not the case here). The *scalar* part is the most important notion: if one of the subqueries returns more than one row (or more than one column), then it cannot be used as an operand in the arithmetic operation, and the query errors.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. Is there any way to distinguish a *scalar subquery* that is part of an expression and one that just returns the value directly? An example would be: `SELECT (select ...)` vs `SELECT 1+(select ...)` the latter involves some manipulation after the scalar subquery is returned. Maybe something like "non-terminal scalar subquery".

Comment: @David542: no, there is no specific technical term that I know about for specifically this.

Answer (score 1):

This subquery probably does not do what you expect:

```
(SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM tbl WHERE name = tbl.name)
```

It is interpreted as:

```
(SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM tbl WHERE tbl.name = tbl.name)
```

**Always qualify all column references in a query that has more than one table reference!**. This is particularly important for correlated subqueries.

Which (assuming that `name` is never `NULL`) is the same as:

```
(SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM tbl)
```

So, this is an example of a *scalar subquery*.  That is, a subquery that returns one value and at most one row.

You *probably* intend for this to be a *scalar correlated subquery*.  That would be a *scalar subquery* that has a condition connecting to the outer table.  It would be expressed as:

```
(SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM tbl tbl2 WHERE tbl2.name = tbl.name)
```

However, I don't recommend a subquery at all for this purpose.  Simply use window functions:

```
SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
```